# Deleting a linked list node

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is a classic linked list problem.

1. Deleting a node from linked list given the data to be deleted.
2. Inserting a node in a sorted linked list.

I saw various versions of this and here is my version. Could you check and let me know if this code is efficient?

```
void deletenode(struct node *&first, int data) 
{
    struct node * current = first;// first will have the node after deletion

    struct node * prev = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        if(current->data!=data)
        {
            prev=current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = current->next;
            delete current;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void insertinsortedlist(struct node *& first, int data)
{
    struct node * current = first;// first will have the node after insertion
    struct node * newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = data;
    struct node * temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    while(current)
    {
        if((current->data < data) && (current->next->data > data))
        {
            temp = current->next;
            current->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = temp;
            break;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future please indent your code by 4 spaces or use the code button (the one with the ones and zeros) to properly format your code.

Comment: It's difficult to give a full review of your code without seeing your definition of `node`.

Comment: This program has a bug.  If I want to delete the first node, it will not work.  This is wrong: `prev=first=null
prev.next !=null`

Comment: This code looks more like C than C++ to me

Answer (score 10):

The efficiency of your algorithm is fine, however there are a couple of other things you should take care of:

First of all do **not** free memory, which was allocated with `malloc`, using `delete`. `delete` is for freeing memory which was allocated with `new`. To free `malloc`ed memory use `free`. Using `delete` on `malloc`ed memory is **wrong** and leads to undefined behavior.

Also there is almost never a good reason to use `malloc` in C++ code. If in doubt use `new` and `delete`.

Another serious bug in your code is that you allocate memory for `prev` in `deletenode`, but never free it.

---

I also don't see why you pass in `first` as a reference to a pointer. Since you never change `first`, I see no reason not to pass it in as a plain pointer (or a plain reference which you then take the address of to assign to `current`).

---

Another thing is that you don't need to add the `struct` keyword when declaring variables or parameters containing structs in C++ - that's a C thing. You should remove it as it only adds noise.

Comment: All the above, and don't malloc a new node for `previous` in the first place. Instead, check if `previous` is still `NULL` once you found the node to be deleted. If it is, assign `first = first->next` to delete the first node.

Comment: To back this point up it's worth noting that if you use malloc to create instances of C++ objects, then the constructors won't get called. You'd have to use "placement new" manually after allocating the memory. This holds for destruction as well (ie. free doesn't call destructors).